# Cannot get square root of negative number

Tags: java, math

I am currently trying to get the square root of -1, but in java, Math.sqrt() return NaN for any negative value. How do I get the square root of -1 in Java?

Comment: You don't, not with the JDK's `Number` classes at least. Find a library that works with imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the square root of a negative number. What you could do is to create a Complex number class with methods to carry out complex number arithmetic. You may have a look here for an example: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use this
if(x<0){
System.out.println("root of num "+Math.sqrt(x*(-1))+"i");}

Answer (score 1):

This is a method that will return a string representation of the square root:

```
    static String sqrtImaginaryNum(int i){
    String str ="";
    double sqrtI =  Math.sqrt(Math.abs(i));
    if(i<0){

        return str+=sqrtI+"i";
    }
    return str+=sqrtI;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I have an easier way so that the next person coming here would get help.

```
if(num<0){
    num = -num;
    ans = Math.pow(num, 0.5);
    System.out.println("The result is: " + ans + "i");
}
```

Input = -16.
Output = 4i

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner for you:

Since any negative number's square root is a positive number.
Just multiply the number with -1 under the square-root in case it's negative:

```
var x = -1;
Math.sqrt(x<0 ? x * -1 : x);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, there aren't real numbers of negative square roots. But there are in imaginary numbers. The GNU Scientific Library can manage this kind of problems, for example, the funcion gsl_complex_sqrt_real.
This library were created in C/C++ but you can port it to java.

Or you can try: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html

This is a very simple example using Apache Commons:

```
Complex number = new Complex(-4);
System.out.println("Square root: " + number.sqrt());
```

The result is:

```
Square root: (0.0, 2.0)
```

The meaning is 0.0 in real part and 2.0 in imaginary part. Or just -2i and 2i.