# how to assign a complex number to Set<Integer> z?

Tags: java, methods, set

How to make the method roots check imaginary roots and real one then return their values?

package warmup;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Quadratic {

```
/**
 * Find the integer roots of a quadratic equation, ax^2 + bx + c = 0.
 * @param a coefficient of x^2
 * @param b coefficient of x
 * @param c constant term.  Requires that a, b, and c are not ALL zero.
 * @return all integers x such that ax^2 + bx + c = 0.
 */
  public static Set<Integer> roots(int a, int b, int c) {
      Set<Integer> z = new HashSet<>();
      int temp1 = (int)(Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c));
    if(a !=0){
        if(temp1 >= 0){
             Integer x1 = (int) ((-b + temp1) / (2*a));
             Integer x2 = (int) ((-b - temp1) / (2*a));        

             z.add(x1);
             z.add(x2);
        } else if (temp1 < 0){
            Integer x1 = (int) ((-b + temp1) / (2*a));
         Integer x2 = (int) ((-b - temp1) / (2*a));        

         z.add(x1);
         z.add(x2);

        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: division by zero.");
    }
    return z;

}


/**
 * Main function of program.
 * @param args command-line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("For the equation x^2 - 4x + 3 = 0, the possible solutions are:");
    Set<Integer> result = roots(1, -4, 3);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: if temp1< 0 its imaginary isnt it.. then just return the set back to main funciton

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: posted an answer.. have a look and let me know if you have doubts

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama my problem is how to make the value of the complex root assigned to the Set? and how to return it my code checks the cases but i dun know how to assign the complex one to the Set?

Comment: are you saying if value is sqrt(-10).. you dont know how to assign it to set?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama Yes my code must be checking the conditions right but if sqrt(-10) how to assign this to the Set?

Comment: oh then sorry buddy.. Java doesnt allow that... i have provided few link to you in answer section.. have a look hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to assign a negative square root number value to java is not allowed in JDK.

what you can do is, you can create a complex number class of your own and do your own operations there. Here is the example which i found online:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html

I also looked at SO for similar questions like yours and i got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747310/cannot-get-square-root-of-negative-number)

Hope this helps